# 404 on weblogic hello world application

Tags: weblogic, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to run a simple hello world web application to make sure I've got the structure of everything right.

Here's what I've got:

```
ear_test.ear
ear_test.ear/META-INF
ear_test.ear/META-INF/application.xml        
ear_test.ear/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ear_test.ear/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml    
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war/META-INF
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war/WEB-INF/classes
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war/WEB-INF/lib
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
ear_test.ear/test_web_project_1.war/helloWorld.jsp
```

**application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>ear_test</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>test_web_project_1.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/test_web_project_1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

**weblogic-application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <weblogic-application>
        <session-descriptor>
            <cookie-name>WLSSessionID</cookie-name>
            <cookie-http-only>false</cookie-http-only>
            <debug-enabled>false</debug-enabled>
            <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
        </session-descriptor>
    </weblogic-application>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>test_web_project_1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>helloWorld.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I can deploy this to weblogic and it shows as active.

However when I try access the webapp, via:

`http://myserver:7011/test_web_project_1`

I get a 404 error.

Any suggestions for resolving this?

Comment: Port 7011 suggests you are expecting it to have been deployed to a managed server in a multi-server domain.  Are you sure the deployment has been targeted at the correct server/cluster and not the Admin server by mistake?

Comment: What errors do you see in the weblogic logs when you try to access it?

Comment: Was using the wrong server in the URL... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your URL again, make sure you are actually referencing the right URL for the server your application is deployed on.